# Blender's progress reports are flooding the terminal, how to disable?

Tags: python

Import OBJ uses the `progress_report` module, which prints out a lot of information into the console, how can this be silenced when called from a script?

---

*Asking on behalf of a developer who emailed me :)*

Answer (score 4):

To quiet the output you can override progress_report's `print` function, after this is done, any use of the progress module won't print to the terminal.

The following examples show how you can disable printing on startup using the command line argument `--python-expr`, the same code can be run from your own scripts too.

2.7x stable:

```
blender --python-expr "import progress_report; setattr(progress_report, 'print', lambda *_, **__: None)"
```

Master and 2.8x

```
blender --python-expr "from bpy_extras.wm_utils import progress_report; setattr(progress_report, 'print', lambda *_, **__: None)"
```

---

Note, this is known as a [monkey-patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) and is generally considered bad practice in Python, longer term we should probably have a way to manage progress output for import/export scripts.