# How to stop the new OBJ importer/exporter from printing to console

Tags: python, scripting, obj

I would like to stop the new OBJ importer/exporter (`bpy.ops.wm.obj_import()`) from printing to the console. Previously with the old OBJ importer/exporter (`bpy.ops.import_scene.obj()`) it was done [like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121704/blenders-progress-reports-are-flooding-the-terminal-how-to-disable):

```
from bpy_extras.wm_utils import progress_report
setattr(progress_report, "print", lambda *_, **__: None)
```

However this doesn't work for the new one. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Hi. I have tested bpy.ops.wm.obj_import in Blender3.3-alapha, and it only printed 'Timer 'OBJ_import' took 100.6 ms' to the console. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.2. When I use the importer, I also only get the Timer message, but when using the exporter, I get the Timer message and "Writing to `export_path`"